# Activating nav-item according to post method

Tags: php, post

I have 3 different forms, I want the data to remain in the form I send it to, how can I do it?

I send the form, but it calculates the result, but I have to click again on which form I sent from the nav-bar.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 mx-auto">
            <div class="card ">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="bg-white shadow-sm pt-4 pl-2 pr-2 pb-2">
                        <!-- Credit card form tabs -->
                        <ul role="tablist" class="nav bg-light nav-pills rounded nav-fill mb-3">
                            <li class="nav-item"> <a data-toggle="pill" href="#hes1" class="nav-link active show"> <i class="fas fa-credit-card mr-2"></i> Hesap1 </a> </li>
                            <li class="nav-item"> <a data-toggle="pill" href="#hes2" class="nav-link"> <i class="fab fa-paypal mr-2"></i> Hesap2 </a> </li>
                            <li class="nav-item"> <a data-toggle="pill" href="#hes3" class="nav-link"> <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt mr-2"></i> Hesap3 </a> </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div> <!-- End -->
                    <!-- Credit card form content -->
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <!-- credit card info-->
                        <div id="hes1" class="tab-pane fade pt-3 active show">
                            <form action="#hes1" method="post">
                                <div class="form-group"> <label for="username">
                                        <h6>Girilen Fiyat</h6>
                                    </label> <input type="text" name="sayi1" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $_POST["sayi1"]; ?>" required="" class="form-control "> </div>
                                <div class="form-group"> <label for="cardNumber">
                                        <h6>Kampanya Oranı</h6>
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="input-group"> <input type="text" name="sayi2" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $_POST["sayi2"]; ?>" class="form-control " required="">
                                        <div class="input-group-append"> <span class="input-group-text text-muted"> <i class="fab fa-cc-visa mx-1"></i> <i class="fab fa-cc-mastercard mx-1"></i> <i class="fab fa-cc-amex mx-1"></i> </span> </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <div class="form-group"> <label><span class="hidden-xs">
                                                    <h6>Kargo Oranı</h6>
                                                </span></label>
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                             <select name="kargo" class="form-control">
                                             <option value="26.99">26.99</option>
                                             <option value="46.99">46.99</option>
                                             <option value="49.99">49.99</option>
                                             </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <div class="form-group mb-4"> <label data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Three digit CV code on the back of your card">
                                                <h6>Hesap <i class="fa fa-question-circle d-inline"></i></h6>
                                            </label> 
                <select name="secim" class="form-control">
                    <option value="+">Hesap</option>
                </select> </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-footer"> <button type="submit" name="kontrol" class="subscribe btn btn-primary btn-block shadow-sm"> Hesapla </button>
                            
                        </div></form>
                        
                        <div class="container">
           <table class="table table-striped">
                <?php
                if(isset($_POST["kontrol"]))//kontrol adında bir form nesnesi var mı kontrolü yapılıyor
                {
                    $sayi1=$_POST["sayi1"];
                    $sayi2=$_POST["sayi2"];
                    $sayi3=100;
                    $secim=$_POST["secim"];
                    $kargo=$_POST["kargo"];
                    $sonuc=0;
                    $sonuc2=0;
                    $sonuc3=0;
                    
                    if($secim == '+')
                    {
                        $sonuc=$sayi1*$sayi2/$sayi3;
                        $sonuc3=$sayi1-$sonuc;
                        $sonuc2=$sayi1+$sayi2;
                        $sonuc4=$sonuc3*12/100;
                        $sonuc5=$sonuc3-$sonuc4;
                    }
                    
                    
                    echo "<h1 class='text-info'>Musterinin Alacagi=$sonuc3</h1>";
                    echo "<h1 class='text-info'>Komisyon=$sonuc4</h1>";
                    echo "<h1 class='text-info'>Kargo=$kargo</h1>";
                    echo "<h1 class='text-info'>Kazanc=$sonuc5</h1>";
                    echo "<h1 class='text-info'>KargosendenKazanc=$sonuc5</h1>";
                }     
                ?>
            </table>
       </div>
                    </div>
```

I have 3 different forms, I want the data to remain in the form I send it to, how can I do it? I send the form, but it calculates the result, but I have to click again on which form I sent from the nav-bar.

Comment: you must send using JS or when you do not want to do that, re-populate the form if you are going to display it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is, you need a parameter sent with each form that identifies which form has been sent. E.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="formname" value="hes1">
```

You seem to use bootstrap, so you will have to control where to show the css classes "active" and "show":

```
<div id="hes2" class="tab-pane fade pt-3
  <?php if($_POST["formname"] == 'hes2') { ?> active show <?php } ?> ">
```

You will have to do this on all forms and all tabs in the navbar.
Also with the form and navbar item that is selected as a standard you will have to use an adapted if clause to make sure "active show" is set also if no "formname" value is present:

```
<div id="hes1" class="tab-pane fade pt-3
  <?php if($_POST["formname"] == 'hes1' OR empty($_POST["formname"])) { ?> active show <?php } ?> ">
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I got what I wanted, but this code did not work

Comment: <div id="hes1" class="tab-pane fade pt-3
  <?php if($_POST["formname"] == 'hes1' OR empty($_POST["formname"]) { ?> active show <?php } ?> ">

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{'

Comment: broo thank you very very much,  empty($_POST["formname"])  ")" ) sign is missing